# How do I get my hour, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to be zeros?

Tags: java-8, java-time

I'm trying to get my format to be 2016-07-08T00:00:00.000Z.

```
String myDate = "20160708";
LocalDate myLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
OffsetDateTime myOffsetDate = myLocalDate.atTime(OffsetTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));

System.out.println(myOffsetDate); //2016-07-08T14:58:23.170Z
```

Comment: You mean you do not need time, you just need to output `T00:00:00.000Z`?

Comment: I'm trying to also output the the date.

Comment: I've already figured that out )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well don't say "I want it to use the current time"! That's what this is doing:

```
OffsetTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

If you just want an `OffsetDateTime` from a `LocalDate` by providing a zero offset and midnight, you can use:

```
OffsetDateTime myOffsetDate = myLocalDate
    .atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)
    .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Or if you prefer:

```
OffsetDateTime myOffsetDate = myLocalDate
    .atTime(OffsetTime.of(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

(Personally I prefer the first version, myself...)

Note that that's just getting you the right `OffsetDateTime`. If you want to format that with milliseconds and seconds, you'll need to do that explicitly:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
System.out.println(myOffsetDate.format(formatter));
```

As noted in comments, if you're find with a `ZonedDateTime` instead of an `OffsetDateTime`, you can use

```
ZonedDateTime myOffsetDate = myLocalDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: @assylias: True - will add that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to keep the seconds and milliseconds when I try to convert the formatted string back to an OffsetDateTime? It seems to strip out the seconds and milliseconds writing it like OffsetDateTime.parse(formattedString).

Comment: @JohnAyers: You're getting confused between the information which is actually in the `OffsetDateTime`, and what `OffsetDateTime.toString()` happens to return. If you parse your string and then reformat the resulting `OffsetDateTime` with a formatter that displays milliseconds and seconds, you'll see that no information is lost.

Comment: This would be neater: `localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)` (assuming the output can be `ZonedDateTime`)

Comment: @JodaStephen: I was assuming the OP wanted an `OffsetDateTime` later in their code. But I'll add this option in.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if you can get the ISO_INSTANCE date format with the given string using LocalDate. but you can use below java 8 piece of code to get the required format.

```
public String getISO_8601DateFormat(String yyyyMMdd){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String requiredFormat = null;
    try {
        Date inputDate = sdf.parse(yyyyMMdd);
        long dateLongRepresentation = inputDate.getTime();
        long myTimeZoneOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getOffset(inputDate.getTime());
        Instant instance = Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateLongRepresentation + myTimeZoneOffset);
        requiredFormat = instance.toString();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return requiredFormat;
}
```

Enjoy coding with java :)

Comment: Not a good solution. You are mixing the old date-time classes (`Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`) with their replacements, the java.time classes. The old classes are poorly designed, confusing, troublesome, and have a lower resolution (milliseconds versus nanoseconds). Avoid the old classes.  See the [correct Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38270241/642706) by Jon Skeet. Also note the tag on the Question asking for a java.time solution.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the Solution by Jon Skeet is much cleaner (I am a very bad coder :( )

Comment: No, not a bad coder. Java has such a large library of classes, some of them now outmoded, that it can be confusing. If you thoroughly read the JavaDoc on the old date-time classes they try to say “use java.time instead”.